# Make CSVs from Excel Sheet Tabs

Tags: python, excel, csv, xlrd

I'm using the below Python script to make CSVs for Excel sheet with multiple tabs. Even though it doesn't give an error and prints out " CSVs made " I'm unable to find the CSV anywhere that should've been produced. I've made some changes and it still returns blank.

```
def Excel2CSV(ExcelFile, Sheetname, CSVFile):
    import xlrd
    import csv

    file_location = "C:\Users\aqureshi\Desktop\Programming\consolidateddataviewsyellowed.xlsx"
    workbook = xlrd.open_workbook(file_location)
    worksheet = workbook.sheet_by_name ("ARC")
    csvfile = open (ARC.csv,'wb')
    wr = csv.writer (csvfile, quoting = csv.QUOTE_ALL)

    for rownum in xrange (worksheet.nrows):
        wr.writerow(
            list(x.encode('utf-8') if type (x) == type (u'') else x
                 for x in worksheet.row_values (rownum)))

        csvfile.close()

    print(Excel2CSV())
```

Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: The script you posted does the following : 1.  Defines a function named `Excel2CSV` and 2. prints  `"CSV made"`.  You have to at some point actually run `Excel2CSV`.  i.e. somewhere before `print("CSV made")`, `Excel2CSV(*args, **kwargs)`

Comment: ARC.csv should be a string as well